# attribute 51 of type users has wrong type

Tags: postgresql, insert, copy

I'm trying to import data to a pg table from a csv file. The error I get is:

```
$ psql -U postgres -c "COPY users (first_name) FROM '/users.csv' (FORMAT csv)"
ERROR:  attribute 51 of type users has wrong type
DETAIL:  Table has type integer, but query expects character varying.
CONTEXT:  COPY users, line 1
```

How do I know which attribute is it about? For that matter an INSERT also fails:

```
$ psql -U postgres -c "INSERT INTO users (first_name) VALUES ('first_name')"
ERROR:  attribute 51 of type record has wrong type
DETAIL:  Table has type integer, but query expects character varying.
```

I tried to count according to the `\d users` output, and to the `attnum` value:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM pg_attribute a
    JOIN pg_class c on a.attrelid = c.oid
    JOIN pg_namespace n on c.relnamespace = n.oid
WHERE n.nspname = 'public'
    AND c.relname = 'users'
    AND attnum >= 1
ORDER BY attnum
```

I'm running PostgreSQL 12.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number corresponds to the `pg_attribute.attnum` value. I followed [the following advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/656841/52499) to reorder columns. It appears indexes refer to columns using `attnum` values. In other words, after reordering columns, they started to refer to other columns, which led to the error.

To reproduce the issue ([script](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/8c207b1ab7a3cbc81b40550a55acecd2)), create a table:

```
> CREATE TABLE t1 (f1 varchar, f2 varchar, f3 integer)
CREATE TABLE

> CREATE INDEX ON t1 (f2) WHERE f2 IS NOT NULL
CREATE INDEX

> \d t1
                      Table "public.t1"
 Column |       Type        | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 f1     | character varying |           |          | 
 f2     | character varying |           |          | 
 f3     | integer           |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "t1_f2_idx" btree (f2) WHERE f2 IS NOT NULL
```

Reorder columns:

```
> UPDATE pg_attribute SET attnum = 30001 WHERE attname = 'f2' AND attrelid = 16384
UPDATE 1

> UPDATE pg_attribute SET attnum = 30002 WHERE attname = 'f3' AND attrelid = 16384
UPDATE 1

> UPDATE pg_attribute SET attnum = 3 WHERE attname = 'f2' AND attrelid = 16384
UPDATE 1

> UPDATE pg_attribute SET attnum = 2 WHERE attname = 'f3' AND attrelid = 16384
UPDATE 1

> \d t1
                      Table "public.t1"
 Column |       Type        | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 f1     | character varying |           |          | 
 f3     | integer           |           |          | 
 f2     | character varying |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "t1_f2_idx" btree (f3 COLLATE "default" text_ops) WHERE f3 IS NOT NULL
```

Try to insert a row:

```
> INSERT INTO t1 (f1) VALUES ('f1')
ERROR:  attribute 2 of type record has wrong type
DETAIL:  Table has type integer, but query expects character varying.

> SELECT a.attname, a.attnum
FROM pg_attribute a
    JOIN pg_class c on a.attrelid = c.oid
    JOIN pg_namespace n on c.relnamespace = n.oid
WHERE n.nspname = 'public'
    AND c.relname = 't1'
    AND attnum >= 1
ORDER BY attnum
 attname | attnum 
---------+--------
 f1      |      1
 f3      |      2
 f2      |      3
(3 rows)
```

As you can see `t1_f2_idx` now refers to `f3` (in the table it's an integer, in the index a string).

At least in this case it's reversible:

```
> UPDATE pg_attribute SET attnum = 30001 WHERE attname = 'f2' AND attrelid = 16384
UPDATE 1

> UPDATE pg_attribute SET attnum = 30002 WHERE attname = 'f3' AND attrelid = 16384
UPDATE 1

> UPDATE pg_attribute SET attnum = 2 WHERE attname = 'f2' AND attrelid = 16384
UPDATE 1

> UPDATE pg_attribute SET attnum = 3 WHERE attname = 'f3' AND attrelid = 16384
UPDATE 1

> INSERT INTO t1 (f1) VALUES ('f1')
INSERT 0 1
```

Comment: If you modify catalog tables, you will break the database. Don't do that.